# Outlook 2016 showing appointment Icon even for meetings created with EWS API

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, outlook-2016

I'm creating appointments and meeting with EWS managed API but however, I found the Icon's appearing wrongly in Outlook 2016.

Creating meetings with msdn example ` ExchangeService service = GetExchangeService();
            Appointment meeting = new Appointment(service);

```
        // Set the properties on the meeting object to create the meeting.
        meeting.Subject = "EWS : Meeting";
        meeting.Body = "Let's learn to really work as a team and then have lunch!";
        meeting.Start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
        meeting.End = meeting.Start.AddHours(4);
        meeting.Location = "Conference Room 12";
        meeting.RequiredAttendees.Add("attendee1");
        meeting.RequiredAttendees.Add("attendee2");
        meeting.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60;

        //// Save the meeting to the Calendar folder and send the meeting request.
        meeting.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);

        // Verify that the meeting was created.
        Item item = Item.Bind(service, meeting.Id, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties));
        Console.WriteLine("\nMeeting created: " + item.Subject + "\n");`
```

But the Icons are like this [image: Outlook image] .
Here , Subject starting with "EWS" created using API and subject with "Outlook" are manually created in outlook. Outlook meeting has different Icon.

Any workaround for this problem?

Comment: [EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633661(v=exchg.80).aspx ) has "real" emails - maybe it detects invalid ones and displays the Icon accordingly?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I know the different types in Outlook. 

For future readers
Appointment  : Single user with specific time ,
Meeting         : More than one user with specific time ,
Event             : An appointment with all day ,
Invited Event : A meeting with all day.

But, however we always see appointment Icon in Outlook when its created using EWS API.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the PR_Icon_Index property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815472.aspx which you should be able to set using a Extended property to 0x00000402 for a single instance meeting.

Comment: Thanks for reply Glen. I initially thought of setting IconIndex ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.iconindex(v=exchg.80).aspx ) but its a get property. 

I will try PR_Icon_Index and let you know the results.